# creating a report/catalog item using REST API in SSRS 2017

Tags: reporting-services, rest

I am trying to create a report/catalog item using the SSRS REST APIs documented [here](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/microsoft-rs/SSRS/2.0#).

I can successfully **create folders** and **resources** using the json:

```
{
"Name": "Test_Report",
"Description": "",
"Path": "MyFolder/Test_Report",
"Type": "ReportModel",
"Hidden": false,
"ModifiedBy": "User",
"CreatedBy": "User",
"ParentFolderId": null,
"IsFavorite": false,
"ContentType": null,
"Content": "" }
```

However when creating a report or catalog item, I am getting HTTP 500 or 400 errors like: [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkaOD.png)

My questions are:

1. what should be the values for "ContentType" and "Content"
2. In the server stub generated from the [swaggerhub](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/microsoft-rs/SSRS/2.0#/CatalogItem), the description for "Content" is:

> A string value that contains binary encoding by base64url encoding rules

what does this mean exactly? and what should be the "ContentType" for this?

3. Is there any other way to create a report or catalog item using the REST API?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it the issue is with Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject() and HttpClient.PostAsync() methods.

Sending a request with [Restsharp](https://restsharp.dev/getting-started/) does the job